# Python pandas - show relationship between values of same column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe consisting of two columns : animals and their weight.

Two rows : cat is 10 pounds, dog is 20 pounds

I want to have an output that shows the relationship between all column values.  In below desired output dataframe, the value is the weight of row animal minus the weight of column animal.

```
    cat  dog
cat 0    -10
dog 10   0
```

I tried pivot_table, but it doesn't seem to be right tool for having index and column as same value.

`pd.pivot_table(df, index=['animal'], columns=['animal copy'], values=['weight'], aggfunc=np.diff)`

results in error.  Np.sum only has values of identical animals.

Comment: can you show the df and the expected output, not sure what the `<br/>` is showing

Comment: Heh wasn't sure how to show a table; got rid of the line break, needed it in preview of post for some reason

Comment: i edit your data frame with the values I think you want to show, can you also show the initial df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to construct the "pivot table" manually using a loop:

```
# Starting dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"animal": ["dog", "cat", "donkey"], "weight": [20, 10, 200]})

weights = dict(zip(df["animal"], df["weight"]))
animals = weights.keys()
pt = pd.DataFrame(columns=animals, index=animals)
for column in pt.columns:
    pt[column] = weights[column] - pt.index.map(weights)
```

I'm sure there's a nicer pandas inbuilt way to do it though so would be interested to see it.

Comment: Worked great thanks!  I agree, seems like it would be common enough for a built-in tool, but couldn't find it.

Comment: You can replace the loop with a call to `np.subtract.outer`. https://pastebin.com/X52JjP3X